# How to have english digits in some posts with an rtl Wordpress theme

Tags: multi-language, language

I have an RTL theme for Wordpress. When I want to have a post in which some digits should intentionally be in English, the theme tends to convert all the digits from English to Persian.

Adding `lang="en"` to the posts did not work. Any ideas how I might get rid of this problem?

Thanks